# sed command to replace specific value after finding specific pattern

Tags: sed

I'm a bit stuck with a unix command.

I have a file called file.txt with the following content:

Customer1

name=Alice

pass=unix

dob=

Customer2

name=Destroyer

pass=windows

dob=

What I basically want is to use a unix command that would allow me to grep for the customer (i.e Customer1) then give its dob a value, say for example dob=1912

so the file.txt will become like

Customer1

name=Alice

pass=unix

dob=1912

I've been working with sed, here's the command that I formulated:

sed "s/$(awk 'c-->0;/Customer1/{c=3}' file.txt | tail -1)/dob=1234/g" -i file.txt

This however will replace ALL occurrences of dob with dob=1234 (quite obvious).

Can someone give me a hint on how to lock on the specific dob for each customer and replace it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk can do it by itself. see the one liner below:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{RS="dob=";OFS="\n\n"}$1~/Customer1/{$0=$0"dob=1234";print}' input
```

**test** : change customer1's dob value to 7777:

```
kent$  cat t.txt
Customer1

name=Alice

pass=unix

dob=

Customer2

name=Destroyer

pass=windows

dob=

kent$  awk 'BEGIN{RS="dob=";OFS="\n\n"}$1~/Customer1/{$0=$0"dob=7777";print}' t.txt

Customer1

name=Alice

pass=unix

dob=7777
```

updated:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{RS="dob=";OFS="\n\n"}$1~/Customer1/{$0=$0"dob=7777";print > "t.txt"}' t.txt

kent$  cat t.txt
Customer1

name=Alice

pass=unix

dob=7777
```

**updated again**

```
kent$  awk '/Customer1/{a++;}/dob=/&&a{$0="dob=7777";a=0;}1' t.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt t.txt

kent$  cat t.txt
Customer1

name=Alice

pass=unix

dob=7777

Customer2

name=Destroyer

pass=windows

dob=
```

**updated with sed**
actually, using sed (with convenient -i option) to handle this is also possible. I didn't understand your requirement correctly, I thought you only want the specific Customer Block. so I picked awk. Now comes the sed version:

```
kent$  sed -ir '/Customer1/{x;s/.*/a/;x;} 
/dob=/{x;
        /a/{s/a//g; x;
                s/.*/dob=1234/; x;};
        x}' t.txt

kent$  cat t.txt
Customer1

name=Alice

pass=unix

dob=1234

Customer2

name=Destroyer

pass=windows

dob=
```

Comment: The command works fine :) Thanks a lot. I have a question though, I want to replace the dob and save the file. I cannot use redirection of course, how do you suggest I proceed? I used sed because of the -i option, waiting your reply, thanks again :)

Comment: Is there a possible way to avoid redirection in this case?

Comment: Just saw it, well that would overwrite the file, I just want to modify the dob field, because if I have multiple customers (Customer2, Customer3 etc) the fields will be gone. Any possible solution for that? Sorry for bothering!!

Comment: Is this a new requirement? ;)  In your Question below "so the file.txt will become like" shows only customer1.

Comment: "Can someone give me a hint on how to lock on the specific dob for each customer and replace it?" That was the question, hope to find a way :)

Comment: @FredGhosn  No problem. P.S. some other Info. see my last update in answer.

Comment: Kent thanks again and again, I tried that command and it worked. Which got me thinking, I tried to use the command like the following (On one single line) : sed -ir '/Customergp1/{x;s/.*/a/;x;} /gc=/{x; /a/{s/a//g; x; s/.*/gc=1111/; x;}; x}' list.txt but I got an error saying extra characters after command. Is that due to the semicolons you used? Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk's pattern matching to limit the range of lines.  For example, (assuming your input file uses "user" instead of "name", as you give both examples):

```
$ awk /user=alice/,/^Customer/{ if( $0 == "dob=" ) $0="dob=1234"} {print} file.txt
```

Should replace alice's dob with "1234"

If you have gnu sed, you can use -i to replace the text in the file (test it before you do that).  Or use redirections as needed.

Answer (score 0):

In this case using awk could help:

```
 searchfor=Customer1
 replacefield=dob
 newvalue=1912

 awk -F'=' '
   /^'"$searchfor"'$/ { do_something = 1 }
   do_something && $1 == "'"$replacefield"'" { print $1 "='"$newvalue"'"; do_something = 0; next }
   { print }
 ' dat1
```